# Has support of Firemonkey for Android ended with SDK 25?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have Delphi CE 10.3.3 and make first experiences with device independant development of Firemonkey. The sample project NativeControlsDemo runs on a Huawei LLD-L31 smartphone with Android 28 very good (32 and 64 Bit). But my Samsung Galaxy M31 is not recognized by Delphi (not shown in the device list). The Samsung runs Android 30. The debugger options are activated and I can successful debug with Android Studio.

Android SDK 25.2.5 is the latest version in the target configuration. Why is my Samsung not usable? Does Firemonkey not support newer Android versions?

For new applications is the lifecycle very important. New features of hardware and OS should be supported  from the development system as soon as possible and maintained as long as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi 10.4.2, which was [released in February 2021](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/announcing-the-availability-of-rad-studio-10-4-2-sydney-release-2/), adds support for Android 11 (API 30).

The highest version that Delphi 10.3.3 supports is Android 10 (API 29).  The 10.3 documentation says:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Prerequisites

> During product installation, RAD Studio installs the Android SDK Tools Revision 25.2.5 and the Android NDK. It includes:
>
> - The Android OS Version 9.0 (API Level 26)
> - The Android NDK (android-ndk-17b)

So if you want to use a higher API, you will have to install it yourself.  You may need to install an up-to-date version of the Android SDK Manager to gain access to higher SDKs/APIs.

A Community Edition of Delphi 10.4.2 was [released in July 2021](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/delphi-cbuilder-community-editions-now-available-in-version-10-4-2/).

Comment: Ok. That's good to know. Many thanks for the quick response. But what can I do to find out the cause of my Samsung smartphone not being recognized?

Comment: @PeterKloß the IDE uses [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) to access Android devices. So make sure you have the proper ADB driver installed for your device, that the device is running with debug mode enabled, and that the device is recognized by ADB on the command line.

Comment: There is a community edition for 10.4.2 now