# Why is Delphi 10.3 App crashing in Android 11?

Tags: android, delphi

My fairly simple app has been running successfully in all versions of Android up to version 10. When installed in Android 11 it only shows the splash screen and then ends. Under the debugger this is still all that happens. The app is installed and the splash screen appears and closes. A breakpoint at the start of initializing and creating the main screen is never reached. As far as I can tell from documentation on Android upgrade (to 11) there does not seem to be anything I need to do with sdk versions etc. are concerned. Note eliminating the splash screen does not change the result except that a blank screen appears before the crash.

How do I find out what is causing this problem?

Comment: That is called debugging.

Comment: Please refer to this comment on this issue:
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27218?focusedCommentId=88179&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-88179

Comment: Run C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525_20.0.36039.7899\tools\monitor.bat. Configure the filter to show just the log messages from your app and see what the problem is.

Comment: This is most likely the answer
[Support for Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647983/has-support-of-firemonkey-for-android-ended-with-sdk-25#:~:text=Delphi%2010.4.2%2C%20which%20was%20released%203%20weeks%20ago%2C,Android%2010%20%28API%2029%29.%20The%2010.3%20documentation%20says%3A)

Comment: @blackapps he clearly states that the application not even runs under debugger. That is called reading

Answer (score 2):

The highest version that Delphi 10.3.3 supports is Android 10 (API 29).

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page

So if you want to use Android 11, you will have to install Delphi 10.4